# Orthogonal Lie algebras for degenerate bilinear forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field such that $\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{K}) \neq 0$, let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space, and let $\sigma:V \times V \to V$ be a bilinear form. If $\sigma$ is non-degenerate then we know that the Lie algebra
$$
{\frak o}_{\sigma}(V) := [A \in {\frak gl}(V) : \sigma(Av,w) = - \sigma(v,Aw)]
$$
is contained in the special linear algebra ${\frak sl}(V)$. Is this true in the case that $\sigma \neq 0$ is degenerate? Does it still hold true for non-zero characteristic?

Comment: Obviously not if $\sigma=0$. And I would expect characteristic $2$ to be exceptional.

Comment: I think you're missing a sign: $\sigma(Av,w)=-\sigma(v,Aw)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments: I have added the sign and excluded the zero case.

Comment: The answer is negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sigma$ is represented by a matrix $B$, so $\sigma(v,w)=v^\top Bw$, then the condition on $A$ becomes $A^\top B=-BA$. If $\sigma$ is non-degenerate, then we get $\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr}(A^\top)=\text{tr}(-BAB^{-1})=-\text{tr}(A)$ and thus $\text{tr}(A)=0$ if the characteristic is not $2$.

For degenerate $\sigma$, take $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. It is clear that $A^\top B=-BA=0$, but $\text{tr}(A)\neq0$, so $A$ is not in $\mathfrak{sl}(\mathbb K^2)$.

For non-degenerate $\sigma$ in characteristic $2$, take $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.